# After changing button color of drawable my stroke is gone and I cannot set the stroke again

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, stroke

I am changing the color of one of my buttons which is a drawable shape, but it removes the stroke. I try to set the stroke again, but it isn't working.

It needs to be mutable since I am using this shape with other buttons

Activity:

```
val bottomButton: Button = this.bottomButton
val drawable = bottomButton.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(backBtnColor,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
drawable.setStroke(5,lightBgColor)
```

XML Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <corners
            android:radius="150dp" />

    <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="20dp"
            android:bottom="20dp"/>

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</shape>
```

I set the drawable in the Layout XML

```
<Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded" tools:text="Options" android:text="Options"/>
```

The result is that the new color fills the entire button (which is good that the color changes) but it removes the Stroke. I want the new color, but retain the stroke, or at the very least let me set the stroke back to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

In Activity file:

```
val backBtnColor:Int = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
val bottomButton: Button = this.bottomButton
val drawable = bottomButton.getBackground().mutate() as GradientDrawable
drawable.setColor(backBtnColor)
```

the key is to add `mutate()` to the `val drawable` when declaring it, not when you call it later. This gives you the ability to `setColor()` which is the property you need.